# How to train Naive Bayes in Python Pandas with str features

Tags: string, pandas, naivebayes

I have a mushroom dataset with 8124 rows and 23 columns. The first column is called 'class' and has two types of values: 'p' (poison) and 'e'(eatable). I want to train Naive Bayes using first 6000 rows. But I dont know how to do it with categorial features. All elements in my dataset have str type.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

df = pd.read_csv('/home/mot/PythonFiles/Mushrooms/mushrooms.csv', delimiter=',')
df_train = df.loc[:6000]
df_test = df.loc[6000:]

df_train_values = df_train.loc[:, 'cap-shape'::]
df_train_answers = df_train['class']

df_test_values = df_test.loc[:, 'cap-shape'::]
df_test_answers = df_test['class']

clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(df_test_values, df_test_answers)
```

That is what I get: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'p'

Comment: create `dummies` or use `one-hot-encoding`

Answer (score 0):

Actually naive Bayes revolves around the idea of P(class|feature). So, if you have 2 classes as you mentioned (poison|edible), then the naive Bayes probability you would want is:

P(edible|features) = P(edible) * P(cap_shape|edible)/(normalizing_constant)

P(poison|features) = P(poison) *  P(cap_shape|poison)/(normalizing_constant)

In general, you would do this if you have more features:

P(class_1|features) = P(class_1) * P(feature_1|class_1) * P(feature_2|class_1) * ... * P(feature_n|class_1)
.
.
.
P(class_m|features) = P(class_m) * P(feature_1|class_m) * P(feature_2|class_m) * ... * P(feature_n|class_m)

This is the general approach to naive Bayes. The probabilities can be estimated from your training data based on proportions, i.e. given class_m, the proportion of feature_1 being seen for class_m.

If you're wondering why I didn't add the divisor (the normalizing constant), it is because it is just that - a normalizing constant. However, due to this, one note of caution is that since we are dealing with proportions (numbers < 1), especially when the dataset is sparse, then mathematical underflow errors may occur in most programming languages. This is a very low number (close to 0) that is limited by how many bytes can be used to represent floating-point decimals. One way to correct for this is to normalize at each calculation step in the divisor in order to prevent underflow from occurring.

Comment: Thank you, I have already done it, and it seems to be working, but I was given two exersices at my classes. 1) Train Naive Bayes using function from library and 2)Write Naive Bayes classifier by myself. The second one is done, but I still have a question about ex1. How can I use GaussianNB from sklearn if all my features are str type?

Comment: You can use `CountVectorizer` using the `vocabulary` parameter in order to get aggregate counts per row, or one-hot encoding or dummy variables as @AkshayNevrekar mentioned above. I didn't realize you had already done the part above that I suggested - the question wasn't completely clear in that respect.  Have you explored other approaches other than the ones I mentioned or @AkshayNevrekar did?